# Python - How to turn thread into thread-safe

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety

So I have been figuring how I should make a thread-safe, the reason for it was that whenever I ran the program that I created just for fun. I realized the console got so much spammed that it doesn't happen to be fast enough to print it one by one.

Basically what I did is that I use a list of list that is no special than just a list of different fruits lets say

```
list = ['apple','banana','kiwi'....]
```

and then I have something called `data` that basically prints out using logger.

```
logger.log(data)
```

The full program would look like something like

```
 def sendData(list, data):

     logger.log(data)

 def main():
    ...
    ...
    ...
    data_list.append((list[i], data))

    for index, data in data_list:
         threading.Thread(target=sendData, args=(list, data)).start()
```

So basically as we can see this would probably be a lot of threads running at the same time which would cause a interact that would make the console to print out alot of mistake so now the question is:

How can I turn this into a sort of thread-safe? Would sort of sleep for each thread start be the magic?

Comment: You might want to look into threading.Lock(), it can be used to prevent multiples threads from doing output tasks at the same time and thus mixing the words in the console.

Comment: Do you have any example of how it could look like out from my code example? @Cyphall

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look into `threading.Lock()`, it can be used to prevent multiples threads from doing output tasks at the same time and thus mixing the words in the console :

```
def sendData(list, data):
    with lock:
        logger.log(data)

lock = threading.Lock()
def main():
    ...
    ...
    ...
    data_list.append((list[i], data))

    for index, data in data_list:
         threading.Thread(target=sendData, args=(list, data)).start()
```

This will prevent multiple threads from running the code in the "with" at the same time.

When a thread X enter in the "with" block, it will claim the lock. If another thread try to claim it (enter the "with" block), it will have to wait until the lock is released by the thread X.